# Swift:remove space below footer of tableview controller embedded in navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, footer

I just want to remove the space below the footer view. it is showing on all versions of iPhone 11. I want my footer to always display on the screen and not at the end of section cells.[screenshot of my tableview controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYTPX.png)

here is my code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footer=tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "footerCell") as! FooterCell
        return footer
    }
class FooterCell:PostSectionBase{

    lazy var button:UIButton={
            let button=UIButton()
                     button.layer.cornerRadius=10
                     button.layer.borderColor=UIColor(red: 59/255, green: 178/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
                     button.layer.borderWidth=1
        button.backgroundColor=UIColor(red: 59/255, green: 178/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1)
                     button.setTitle("Confirm", for: .normal)
                     button.titleLabel?.font=UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 19)
                     button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
                     button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
                     return button
        }()

    override func setupViews(){
        setupContainerView()
    }
    func setupContainerView(){
        addSubview(button)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-40-[v0]-40-|", views: button)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-40-[v0(40)]-40-|", views: button)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to implement this is make a UIViewController. Then add tableView as a subview of it. You can also add footer view as a subview of ViewController's view not tableView. It works fine.